# How to iterate document.getElementsByClass

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a PHP while loop getting information from my database and I have a JS script that uses ajax to run a script.

JS File

```
var class_id = document.getElementsByClassName('group_id');

for(var i = 0; i < class_id.length; i++){
  var id = class_id[i].value+',';
}

xmlhttp.open('POST', 'ajax/delete_group.php?id='+id, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xmlhttp.send();
```

My goal is to get the real value associated with which ever row I click in the loop instead of the value of the 1st row with the class `group_id`

The variable `id` is giving me an `ndefined result` and if it's not doing that, it's giving me the 1st value of the 1st row in the loop.

How can I make javascript use the class value associated with the row I click on.

Now that I'm trying with this for loop in JS it returns undefined.

Please help me.

This is the class I'm trying to get, it's in a PHP loop

```
<li><a class="delete_group">Delete</a>   
 <div name="group_id" class="group_id" id="group_id" hidden>'.$group_id.'</div>  
</li>
```

Comment: Why not use jQuery? Iterating through items is EXTREMELY easy that way - additionally you will have better results with ajax when it comes to cross-browser support.

Comment: Can you show us your click handler as well?

Comment: Since everyone's recommending jQuery ajax I'm gonna take them time out to do it the easy way. @Dutchie432

Comment: @mattchambers: everyone?

Comment: This isn't a not enough jQuery issue. This is a logic issue. You've not provided very much code to show what you're doing, but typically the element "clicked" will be held by the `this` keyword in your event handler.

Comment: Are you trying to fetch the elements before they exist (like immediately in the `<head>`)?

Comment: You're still not showing how you're assigning the behavior to a click event.